# How can I simplify search results from whapi (wikihow api)

Tags: python, filtering

I'm using an unofficial API and when I use search I get long annoying code. This is the code:

```py
wikihowc = input ("What you would like to learn today: ")
earch_results = search((wikihowc), [1])
print(search_results)
```

This is what I get back from the console:

```json
[{'title': 'clean Legos', 'article_id': 1951481, 'url': 'https://www.wikihow.com/Clean-LEGOs'}]
```

Comment: Is this python? And what api library/module are you using?

Comment: What do you want to be simplified? Do you just want the URL or just the article title?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is Python and you're wanting to filter the results to just get the article URL.

If so, you can do that with a list comprehension:

```py
wikihowc = input ("What you would like to learn today: ")
search_results = search((wikihowc), [1])
simplified_results = [result["url"] for result in search_results]
print(search_results)
print(simplified_results)
```